# How to Access MulitPage Page Properties VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a simple wizard tool in VBA. When a button is clicked on the default page of the MultiPage, I wanted the next page to become the current page and the current one to disappear.

I can get the pages to change with `Me.MultiPage1.value = 0, 1, 2...` but I don't know how to make the individual pages visible or not. I see in their properties they have the capability to, but I cant figure out the syntax to do it.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Can you share what you have?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19573496/how-to-dynamically-get-the-value-of-current-multipage-tab-value