# VBA - The right spot to update last row within a For loop

Tags: excel, vba

When I tried to output the value to the worksheet from userform's combobox and textbox, I found that the second or below rows of the combobox and textbox could not update to the worksheet. I realise the problem is caused by missing the line for updating the last row after each time copy the value from the combobox and textbox within the userform.

Here is the outfit of the userform:

[image]

And a part of my codes:

```
Dim Nws As Worksheet, tb1 As ListObject
Dim range_output As Range
Dim n As Long
Dim lRow As Long
Dim Ctrl As Control
Dim strW As String
Set Nws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Fill")
Set range_output = Nws.Range("A19:E30")
Set tb1 = Nws.ListObjects("Output")

With tb1.ListColumns(2).Range
    lRow = .Find(What:="*", After:=.Cells(1), SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1
End With


For Each Ctrl In UserForm1.Controls
    If TypeOf Ctrl Is MSForms.ComboBox Then
        If Ctrl.Value <> "" Then
            Select Case Int(Replace(Ctrl.Name, "ComboBox", ""))
            Case 3 To 12, 23 To 32, 53 to 62   '3&4&5: Location
                Range("A1").Cells(lRow, 1).Value = Ctrl.Value
            Case 13 To 22            '3: Work Type
                Range("A1").Cells(lRow, 2).Value = Ctrl.Value
            Case 33 To 42            '4: Work Type
                n = Int(Replace(Ctrl.Name, "ComboBox", "")) + 10
                strW = "4-" & Ctrl.Value & Controls("ComboBox" & n).Value
                Range("A1").Cells(lRow, 2).Value = strW
            Case 63 To 72            '5: Work Type
                n = Int(Replace(Ctrl.Name, "ComboBox", "")) + 10
                strW = "5-" & Ctrl.Value & Controls("ComboBox" & n).Value
                Range("A1").Cells(lRow, 2).Value = strW
            End Select
        End If
    
    ElseIf TypeOf Ctrl Is MSForms.TextBox Then
        If Ctrl.Value <> "" Then
            Select Case Int(Replace(Ctrl.Name, "TextBox", ""))
            Case 16 To 25, 36 To 45, 56 To 65   'Staff
                Range("A1").Cells(lRow, 3).Value = Ctrl.Value
            Case 26 To 35, 46 To 55, 66 To 75   'Number
                Range("A1").Cells(lRow, 4).Value = Ctrl.Value
            End Select
        End If
    End If
Next Ctrl
```

I want to find the right spot to place the line of `lRow = lRow + 1` . However, it is difficult since I want the same row of the combobox and textbox on the userform output to the same row of the worksheet, ie. Combobox 3, Combobox 13, Textbox 16 and Textbox 26 output to `Cells(lRow, 1 to 4)`.

I have thought about adding another variable `i`. Add `i = i + 0.25` each time `Ctrl` have run, and `lRow = lRow + worksheetfunction.rounddown(i , 0)`. However, the page 3 have 4 items: Location, Work type, Staff and Number, but the page 4 and 5 have 5 items: Location, Work type, Facility, Staff, Number. I cannot make it work.

Thanks.

Comment: Where does Facility go on the sheet?

Comment: @Notus_Panda The Facility only available on the pages 4&5. The Combobox 33 to 42 and 63 to 72 are the work type, and 43 to 52 and 73 to 82 are the facility. When the `comboxbox 33 (work type) + 10 = comboxbox 43 (Facility)`. They will be merged with strW and output to Cells(lRow, 2). The example of the pages 4 & 5 is something like comboxbox 33 is the verb of the work type(ie, wash, repair, replace, etc), and the combobox 43 is the facility(ie. chair, desk, lamp, etc). So that, the result of them would be something like `Cells(lRow,2) = "4-washDesk"`.

Comment: Would it be possible to change the object names to better reflect the position on the form ?

Comment: @CDP1802 Do you mean rename the object like `ComboboxA1,A2,A3,TextboxA4,A5` on the same rows? Thanks for the idea. I think it is feasible If no better option. But the drawback is I have to rename all of the controls.

Comment: @Light: I think the effort to rename all controls is a low price compared to the time you need to maintain your code. However, I would advice to use more talking names, eg `cb_location_1` for the location combobox in row 1 or `tb_staff_4` for the textbox in row 4. In that case the row number is part of the name.

Comment: That way, you can easily check if one is filled in and fill the rest to the table together with accessing the controls by their name [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24083717/referencing-excel-userform-control-name-value-from-string-vba)

Comment: Do you have Comboboxes 42 to 53 ?

Comment: @Notus_Panda If I didn't misunderstand it, does it mean I should delete the line of the `If Ctrl.Value <> ""` ,add the `lRow = lRow + 1` to it, and refer every controls to the worksheet including the empty Comboboxes and Textboxes?

Comment: No, as in, instead of looping through all the controls with a For Each, you loop through the "rows" in your userform, i.e. 1 to 10 and with what FunThomas said, you could have an array you loop through (consisting of the different names, i.e. "cb_location_", "tb_staff_") which you combine with the "row", i.e. `arr(j) & i` which could be something like `cb_location_1` if i and j are both 1 or `cb_workType_1` if i = 1 and j = 2. [Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19573496/how-to-dynamically-get-the-value-of-current-multipage-tab-value) for an example how to know which page you use.

Comment: @CDP1802 Yes. The Comboboxes 43 and 52 are the facility. I didn't put it as the select case's condition because it always combines with the Comboboxes 33 to 42. No need to be triggered. I'm suddenly getting an idea when I answer this question. How about delete `Case 13 to 22, 33 to 42, 63 to 72`? Only leaving`Case 3 To 12, 23 To 32, 53 to 62`. And when Combobox 3(location) have been triggered, also refer `Combobox 13 (n+10) (work type)` in the same select case, and the `textbox 16 (n+13) (staff)`, `textbox 26(n+23) (Number)`. Put the `lRow = lRow + 1` at the end of select case.

Comment: You'd still have them multiple times if you stay in the `For each` loop unless you build in a check with a dictionary to keep track which ones already got processed.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't directly answer your question but consider filling an 3-dimensional array first with all the values from the form. It should be easier then to create the rows to be added to the table. Run this demo in a new workbook, no need to have a form. The result shows object names but can easily be changed to use `UserForm1.Controls(name).Value`

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub demo()

   'create 3D array (page, row, column)
   Dim ar(1 To 5), i As Long, pg
   For i = 1 To 5
      ReDim pg(1 To 10, 1 To 4)
      ar(i) = pg
   Next
   
   ' fill array from form
   FillArrays ar
   
   ' write to sheet
   Range("A1:D10") = ar(3)
   Range("A12:D21") = ar(4)
   Range("A23:D32") = ar(5)
   MsgBox "done"

End Sub

Sub FillArrays(ByRef ar)
   
    Dim r As Long, p As Long, c As Long
    Dim i As Long, s As String
    
    ' comboboxes
    For i = 3 To 72
       
        ' page
        If i >= 53 Then
           p = 5
        Else
           p = 3 + Int((i - 3) / 20)
        End If
        ' row
        r = 1 + (i - 3) Mod 10
        'column
        Select Case i
            Case 3 To 12, 23 To 32, 53 To 62 ' locations
                c = 1
            Case 13 To 22, 33 To 42, 63 To 72 ' work
                c = 2
            Case Else
                c = 0
        End Select
        
        If c > 0 Then
            s = "ComboBox" & i
            ar(p)(r, c) = s 'use UserForm1.Controls(s) to get value
        End If
    Next
        
    ' textboxes
    For i = 16 To 75
        p = 3 + Int((i - 16) / 20)
        r = 1 + (i - 16) Mod 10
        Select Case i
            Case 16 To 25, 36 To 45, 56 To 65   'Staff
                c = 3
            Case 26 To 35, 46 To 55, 66 To 75   'Number
                c = 4
        End Select
        s = "TextBox" & i
        ar(p)(r, c) = s 'use UserForm1.Controls(s) to get value
     Next

End Sub
```